# Eureka instance hostname resolve issue

Tags: netflix-eureka

I have eureka server and eureka clients up and running.

The problematic client name is **trainer-workload-service**

When I try to send a request from another client:
POST http://trainer-workload-service/api/workload/trainer
using RestTemplate annotated with @LoadBalanced, I receive the following exception:
`java.net.UnknownHostException: trainer-workload-service`

The **trainer-workload-service** is being resolved while using WebFlux's WebClient.
Could you please advice what might be the issue?